# Converting script from init to systemd

Tags: scripting, systemd

I am moving from Ubuntu 11 to 16, and would like to convert custom-made scripts to work with Ubuntu 16

I have started and completed **First init script** but need a bit of help on **Second init script**. I have completed part of it, but can't find examples on line to complete it.

First init script

```
description "worker process to start multiple consumers - q9 mt03 local queue"
author      "mt dev team"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env NUM_WORKERS=20

pre-start script
  for i in `seq 1 $NUM_WORKERS`
  do
    start consumer-localhost N=$i
  done
end script
```

Systemd version

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO 
Provides: localqueue 
Default-Start: 2 3 4 5 
Default-Stop: 0 1 6 
Short-Description: start and stop service rabbitmq servers 
Description: worker process to start multiple consumers - q9 mt03 local queue 

Environment NUM_WORKERS=20 
ExecStartPre 
for i in `seq 1 $NUM_WORKERS` 
do 
start consumer-localhost N=$i 
done 
ExecStopPost 
### END INIT INFO
```

Second init script

```
description "consumer script as a service - q9 local queue"

author "mt dev team"

stop on stopping worker-localhost

instance $N

# Automatically Respawn:

respawn

respawn limit 70 5

pre-start script

# script to run before restart - notify or logging script

/bin/sh /root/consumer_restart_log.sh localhost pre-start

end script

script

exec /usr/bin/php /root/tracking/consumer.php localhost $N >>/var/log/aws_consumer_output.log 2>&1

end script

post-start script

# script to run before restart - notify or logging script

/bin/sh /root/consumer_restart_log.sh localhost post-start

end script
```

Systemd version script

```
Description "Consumer script as a service "
author "mt dev"
Conflicts=worker-localhost
```

Comment: I believe you can first put in a stop-gap to just call  enable your init script, no longer called an init script, just a script.  you can `syscemctl enable yourlservice` that way.  The script should run.  If you want to fully convert it, i think you should be hitting the docs.  Your question doesnt ask for doc resource.

Comment: You have been confused by the questioner labelling these files "init scripts", Brian Thomas.  These are _upstart job definitions_, which systemd does not import and which one has to convert by hand.  There is no van Smoorenburg `init`/`rc` here.  Any thinking based upon that, does not apply.  This is Ubuntu.  It hasn't had van Smoorenburg `init`/`rc` for a decade.

Comment: ok, thank you, is there any documentation that can help me to convert it fully please?

Comment: See this wiki [systemd for upstart users](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers).

Comment: ok thank you, I was using that guide, I am trying to convert it word for word and the "instance" variable is throwing me off instance $N , I cant find any examples with it